# which attached usb device is which?

Tags: macos, usb, mount

I have a Macbook Air (2015). It has two identical USB ports, one on the left and one the right.

I bought two identical USB flash drives and plugged both in. I'm copying a single large dataset onto both drives. The first transfer is complete, the second has just begun and will take another hour. I would like to disconnect the drive that I've already transferred the files to. I obviously do not want to disconnect the wrong drive, the drive with an active file transfer. But these drives do not have any kind of activity indicator (like an LED).

So, which drive is which? If the physical devices offer no clue, can I figure this out by consulting fstab or some other low-level system info? Do the physical ports have predictable locations on the internal bus, or anything like that?

I don't expect an answer within the next hour, but I'm still interested in the question academically. When the two USB devices are different, it's easy to know which is which because you put them there and are aware of their differences.

Also: this question is specific to 2015 Macbook Airs. If Apple did things predictably back in 2015, great for me, even if the *nix & Windows situation is the wild west.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you find yourself in the same situation again, you need to first ascertain and mark each *disk* with its `serial number` where you can easily see it, or at least know where it is, if it's already on the outside of the case.

You can run the following *command* in **Terminal** with one disk at a time mounted:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

Review the info and mark the case of the target *disk*. Then do the same for the second *disk*.

Then when you find yourself in this situation again, you can use **Terminal** to determine which *disk* is being written to.

First run the `mount` *command*.

When mounting two *disks* whose *name* are the same, using the `mount` *command* in **Terminal**, the second one mounted will show as e.g. `/dev/disk4s2 on /Volumes/Name 1` while the first one mounted will show as e.g. `/dev/disk3s2 on /Volumes/Name`, e.g.:

```
/dev/disk3s2 on /Volumes/Name (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk4s2 on /Volumes/Name 1 (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
```

Now using `sudo fs_usage -w -f diskio` you'll see lots of messages, e.g.:

```
11:31:08.015616    WrData[ANT1]    D=0x0345b918  B=0x80000  /dev/disk4s2  /System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Name 1/path/to/file
```

Seeing that it's `/dev/disk4s2` being written to, then in this example case, you'd run `diskutil eject disk3` to *eject* the *disk* of the same *name* that's not being written to, under the use case you described in your OP.

You would then run  `system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep -E '.*Serial Number:|.*BSD Name:'` in **Terminal**, looking just at the information where there is a `BSD Name:` immediately following a `Serial Number:` to see which *disk* is, e.g `disk3` by its *serial number* in this example.

Look at the *serial number* on the case of each *disk* and unplug the one that's not being written to base on the output of the *commands* run in **Terminal**.